# Will Daenerys Targaryen get greyscale disease?

Tags: game-of-thrones

In episode 5.5, "[Kill the Boy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kill_the_Boy)", [Jorah Mormont](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jorah_Mormont) gets infected with the greyscale disease that will turn his skin grey and scaly. Infection occurs from simple skin contact, touching those who are infected. His hand and wrist are the first parts to turn grey.

In episode 5.9, "[The Dance of the Dragons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Dance_of_Dragons)", the Sons of the Harpy attack the people at the fighting pits. They try to kill [Daenerys Targaryen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daenerys_Targaryen). Jorah Mormont holds her hands to help her down into the gladiator ring.

[Here is a video of the scene](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQ-LIOFXzgM) and the relevant moments in the scene.

- Fast-forward to 3:45 and then look closely at his hands at 3:51 when he helps her.
- And then fast-forward to 5:59 and look at whom Daenerys touches with her hand.
- Next fast-forward to 8:25 see the next person her hands touch.

Will Daenerys Targaryen get greyscale disease?

When you answer, please provide information from the books that describe the symptoms and infection rates and incubation times from the disease.

Comment: Rules of StackExchange site say: one question per one post

Comment: One question per question please.

Comment: @Schullz Edited post to trim it down to one question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The fact that Tyrion and others haven't been infected perhaps means a direct touch with the infected parts spreads it. Jorah have been covering the infected region. Like when Jorah pulls Tyrion out of the river or when holding Daenerys' hand therefore none of them have been infected.

Answer (score 3):

Daenerys could possibly be infected. But not all touched people became infected. Tyrion wasn't infected after strong touch. If dragon's blood gives immunity, it could be proof of Tyrion having Targaryen ancestors.

So, there are two hypotheses:

1. Not every touch gives infection
2. Targaryens can't be infected

So, Daenerys could still be not infected - each of these hypotheses could save her.

About incubation time: it is just a few days (for Jon Connington in books or for Jorah Mormont in series). So, Daenerys should not be infected - because she spent some days in Drogon's nest without symptoms

Comment: That Targaryens are immune to illness is something of a myth, if I recall correctly. Dozens of them died during the plague called the Spring Sickness, and Dany herself gets dysentery.

Comment: @TenthJustice Dany's "dysentery" is not dysentery it is her unusually intense periods. She checked it. And her diarrhea was without blood.

Comment: I'll admit that I lack experience in these matters, but this is some period: *Sunset found her squatting in the grass, groaning. Every stool was looser than the one before, and smelled fouler. By the time the moon came up she was shitting brown water. The more she drank, the more she shat, but the more she shat, the thirstier she grew, and her thirst sent her crawling to the stream to suck up more water. When she closed her eyes at last, Dany did not know whether she would be strong enough to open them again.*

Comment: @TenthJustice is anywhere mentioned that there was blood in her shit? It's important because blood is one of the most important syndromes of Bloody flux. Dany just ate some strange berries and they were not edible

Comment: WRT Daenerys: it isn't a period or dysentery, but a miscarriage combined with bad nourishment.

Comment: @BCdotWEB oh, we can't understand each other =/
 I was saying that the Deny's blood was from menstruation.